# How to replace negative values with 0 in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to replace all negative with 0 and nan values with 0 in pyspark dataframe with integer columns. I tried

```
df[df < 0] = 0
```

But getting error.

Comment: do you want to replace for particular column or in all columns ?

Comment: all integer columns.

Comment: when you say that you have an error, you post the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace null values with 0 (or any value of your choice) across all columns with df.fillna(0) method. However to replace negative values across columns, I don't there is any direct approach, except using case when on each column as below.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "col1",
    F.when(df["col1"] < 0, 0).when(F.col("col1").isNull(), 0).otherwise(F.col("col1")),
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot steven. One quick question. Can i replace isnull with isnan?

Comment: how to replace null with nan

Comment: or if you want to use it in when clause you can use it like this, "F.when(F.isnan(df["col1"]), 0)"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) and [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) -

`to_convert` - Contains the list of columns you wise to convert to 0

## Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
|-1|100
|10|-10
|200|-300
|-500|300
""".split("|")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: int(x.strip()), input_str[1:]))

input_list = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(input_values[0::2], input_values[1::2])]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, ["a", "b"])

sparkDF.show()
+----+----+
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
|  -1| 100|
|  10| -10|
| 200|-300|
|-500| 300|
+----+----+
```

## Reduce and When

```
to_convert = set(['a'])

sparkDF = reduce(
    lambda df, x: df.withColumn(x, F.when(F.col(x) < 0, 0).otherwise(F.col(x))),
    to_convert,
    sparkDF,
)

sparkDF.show()
+---+----+
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|  0| 100|
| 10| -10|
|200|-300|
|  0| 300|
+---+----+
```

Comment: how to do columnwise in one statement??

Comment: @datatatata replace `to_convert` with `df.columns`. It's written at the begining of the answer

Comment: @datatatata - As Steven mentioned , you can modify `to_convert` to include all the columns you wish to replace with 0

Comment: For all columns, it is actually easier IMO using select `df.select(*[F.when(F.col(col)>=0,F.col(col)).otherwise(0).alias(col) for col in df.columns]).show()`

Answer (score 1):

to set negative values to zero and respect the positive ones, it can be done with greatest, to choose the greatest between negative and zero.

df.withColumn("col1",greatest(col("col1"), lit(0))

This substitutes the values in your column.
Regards.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply